# Is there any way to control the order that calculated controls on a form and subform are calculated in?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a number of calculated controls on subforms within a tab control.  The subforms are checklists that display due dates for production activities, and check boxes showing if an activity is complete or not.  Each subform has two hidden text controls, txtAllDone and txtActionDate, that hold the due date and activity name of the activity due next. These are calculated during the onCurrent event of the subform.  if all activities on the subform are complete, the txtAllDone control is set to "Yes" and the txtActionDate is set to null.

On the parent tab control there are two visible text controls that show the next activity that is due (txtNextAction) and it's due date (txtDueDate).
This is worked out by checking each subform and calculating the data in the OnCurrent event of the parent form.  However, the date displayed in txtdueDate on the parent form is often a 1900 date, as it completes and loads the date before the subforms have finished loading.  I've tried to requery the checklists as part of the parent form OnCurrent to ensure the subforms have loaded and have correct data, but this has made no difference.

Is there any way I can dictate when a calculated control is calculated? 
This is the code in the parent form OnCurrent event -

```
'update the checklists
Me.Contract_Sales_Checklist.Requery
Me.Contract_Eng_Checklist.Requery
Me.Contract_Production_Checklist.Requery
Me.Contract_Client_Checklist.Requery

'update the Next Action box on the checklist
If Me.ContractStatus = "Cancelled" Or IsNull(Me.ContractNo) Then
Me.txtNextAction = Null
Me.txtDueDate = Null
Else

If (Me.[contract sales checklist].Form.txtAllDone = "Yes" And
    Me.[Contract Eng Checklist].Form.txtAllDone = "Yes" And
    Me.[Contract Production Checklist].Form.txtAllDone = "Yes" And
    Me.[Contract Client Checklist].Form.txtAllDone = "Yes") Then
    Me.txtNextAction = "All actions completed"
    Me.txtDueDate = Null
Else
    If Me.[Contract Client Checklist].Form.txtAllDone <> "Yes" Then
    Me.txtNextAction = Me.[Contract Client Checklist].Form.txtAllDone
    Me.txtDueDate = Me.[Contract Client Checklist].Form.txtActionDate
    End If

    If Me.[Contract Production Checklist].Form.txtAllDone <> "Yes" And
    (Me.[Contract Production Checklist].Form.txtActionDate < Me.txtDueDate Or
    IsNull(Me.txtDueDate)) Then
        Me.txtNextAction = Me.[Contract Production Checklist].Form.txtAllDone
        Me.txtDueDate = Me.[Contract Production Checklist].Form.txtActionDate
    End If

    If Me.[Contract Eng Checklist].Form.txtAllDone <> "Yes" And
    (Me.[Contract Eng Checklist].Form.txtActionDate < Me.txtDueDate Or
    IsNull(Me.txtDueDate)) Then
        Me.txtNextAction = Me.[Contract Eng Checklist].Form.txtAllDone
        Me.txtDueDate = Me.[Contract Eng Checklist].Form.txtActionDate
    End If

    If Me.[contract sales checklist].Form.txtAllDone <> "Yes" And
    (Me.[contract sales checklist].Form.txtActionDate < Me.txtDueDate Or
    IsNull(Me.txtDueDate)) Then
        Me.txtNextAction = Me.[contract sales checklist].Form.txtAllDone
        Me.txtDueDate = Me.[contract sales checklist].Form.txtActionDate
    End If
End If
End If
me.repaint
```

Comment: Yes, all calculations in VBA are handled by normal mathematical [(Order of Operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). This applies to both actual mathematics as well as text-based changes. As such, a nested `IF` will proceed in order from first to last (or **FIFO** for that accounting reference) for anything that triggers the `IF` parameters. However, it looks like you might be attempting to ask a more specific question here, what might that be?

Comment: It seems to me that your trigger event *may be* wrong for what you are trying to accomplish. For instance, `AfterUpdate` *may* be the better course of action here.

Comment: Sorry, i’m not quite sure how to phrase it better. It’s not the order of the individual calculations. The problem that occurs is that the calculated controls on the subforms haven’t always been calculated when the code for the parent form completes. My question is can i better control  the order in which the subform code runs to ensure it has completed before the parent form code runs, as that will ensure the correct data is displayed in the parent form controls.  I can’t use the AfterUpdate event as the subform controls are updated from vba so the event isn’t triggered.

Comment: So, are you using `OnCurrent` to run every time you're selecting some sort of record or something (if not, what is triggering it)? My hang up here is that what you're suggesting is not possible, and by that I mean that the calculations do not work that way, they will always fire in the same order *unless* there something in the code preventing it. In case you are unaware, the `OnCurrent` event only fires for the parent form when the form is opened, the focus leaves one record to another, and when the Form’s underlying Table or Query is requeried. This **does not** apply to a subform.

Comment: Yes- the parent form contains data about a contract record. The parent form contains a tab control with multiple tabs containing relevant, grouped data about the contract, eg order items, delivery notes, invoice details. The first tab contains 4 subforms that are made up of check boxes and text fields that are all either calculated and set from vba during the subform OnCurrent event, or are a calculated control. On the same first tab there are the two controls txtNextAction and txtDueDate which are set from the parent form OnCurrent event.

Comment: If I had to venture a guess here, it is possible that the event is not actually firing when you expect it to do so. What you could do to figure that out is put a benign code snippet in your events (such as a MsgBox, debug.print, Stop, etc.) just to confirm the event is actually firing when and where you want it to.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i’d not thought to check the events that way. I’ll give that a whirl tomorrow.